# nativescript-ui-listview throws ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navBar.tintColor = color.ios')

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I try to build a small iOS-App with Angular and Nativescript to display Data from an Webpage.

I like to have the landingpage as an multiline ListView with Name and Teaser.

After i installed the nativescript-ui-listview plugin i wrote following Code:

`

```
<lv:RadListView id="listview" class="list-group">
    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="100" spanCount="2"/>
    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/formular', item.id]" [text]="item.name"
                   class="list-group-item-heading"></Label>
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/formular', item.id]" [text]="item.teaser"
                   class="list-group-item-text"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

`

and now i got that Error:

```
file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar/action-bar.js:328:19: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navBar.tintColor = color.ios')
```

Some Ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: @Laurin_Fritz I face the same error. Did you manage to get it resolved?

Comment: @Wei-jye Excuse me, I don't think I can help you with my solution since I built a big workaround especially for my application.

Comment: @Lautin_Fritz ok thank you for your time